# NextJS Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

When running my npm server I get this error:

```
⨯ ./node_modules/@napi-rs/snappy-win32-x64-msvc/snappy.win32-x64-msvc.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@napi-rs/snappy-win32-x64-msvc/snappy.win32-x64-msvc.node
./node_modules/snappy/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./app/lib/mongodb.js
./app/components/ig-report/getReportData.js
./app/reportdisplay/page.js
```

My next.config.js file is as follows:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
     
        webpack: (config) => {
            config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false, path: false, net: false, tls:false, dns:false};
            config.module.rules.push( { test: /\.js$|jsx/, use: {loader: 'babel-loader',options: {presets: ['@babel/preset-react']}}});
            config.resolve.extensionAlias = {
                ".js": [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
                ".mjs": [".mts", ".mjs"],
                ".cjs": [".cts", ".cjs"],
            };

            config.module.rules.push( { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
           ` use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 8192,
                        name: '[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
                    },
                 },
             ],});

            config.module.rules.push( {test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images/'
                }}});
            

        return config
      }
    }
```

I have tried several solutions, playing around with config settings and loaders. My .babelrc is currently empty as when I include settings I get another error:

```
Syntax error: "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom babel config being present.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict
```